# Displaying HashMap key & value in JSP display table

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags, displaytag

I would like to display the key and value of my Hashmap in the display column of the display table. Below is the code i have right now. Currently its throwing a JSP error saying that the property attribute of the column does not exist

```
<display:table name="myHashMap" id="Property"> 

     <display:column title="Name" sortable="true" property="key"/>
      <display:column title="Value" sortable="true" property="value" />

 </display:table>
```

Answer (score 1):

try it with this code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:forEach items="${map}" var="entry">
    Key = ${entry.key}, value = ${entry.value}<br>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I was going down this path but the problem is that it won't enable me to use the nice features of the <display:column> tag (sort, etc..)